# how to set queue/message durability to false in Spring AMQP using annotations?

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I wrote sample spring amqp producer which is running on RabbitMQ server which sends messages and consuming those messages uisng MessageListener using Spring AMQP. Here, I want to set queue and message durability to false. Could you please any one help me on how to set "durable" flag to false using annotations.

Here is sample code

```java
@Configuration
public class ProducerConfiguration {

    protected final String queueName = "hello.queue";

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        template.setRoutingKey(this.queueName);
        template.setQueue(this.queueName);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }
}


public class Producer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Producer().send();
    }

    public void send() {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                ProducerConfiguration.class);
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue foo() {
        return new Queue("foo", false);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }
}
```

The rabbit admin will declare the queue the first time the connection is opened. Note that you can't change a queue from durable to not; delete it first.